# Passing Capybara session to an page object

Tags: ruby, capybara, rspec3

I'm trying to do simple implementation of page object pattern using capybara and rspec. I'm at the point where I need to initialise a new page object from a different page object instance method. But after initialising the new page object the system complains that

> undefined local variable or method `page'

I guess that I should pass somehow the driver session to the new object but I don know how
Here is my first class:

```
  class DashBoardLoginPage
  include Dashboard
  include Logging
  include Locator
  include Capybara::DSL

  def initialize
    super
    @locator = locators_for :dashboard_login_page_selectors
    log.info "Dashboard Login page initialized"
  end 

  #param user is a hash with name and pass keys 
  def login_user user
    visit '/'

    fill_in user_name_field, with: user[:name]
    fill_in user_password_field, with: user[:password]
    click_button login_button
    page.save_screenshot "#{Time.now.getutc}_screenshot.png"

    dashboard_landing_page = DashboardLandingPage.new
  end
end
```

and my second object:

```
require_relative "dashboard_base"

class DashboardLandingPage < DashboardBasePage

  def initialize
    super
    @locator = locators_for :dashboard_login_page_selectors
    log.info "Dashboard Landing page initialized"
  end

  def is_open?
    page.has_title? "Apps - Fyber Ad Monetization Dashboard"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include Capybara::DSL in DashboardLandingPage

Comment: I'm including it true the `require_relative "dashboard_base"` line. It's a module with all inclusions that I need.

Comment: Actually that was the problem. Thank you very much. I've forgotten to put this line in my module :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

You might be able to access `page` through `Capybara.current_session`.

Also, have you considered using one of the already available page-object gems?  They could simplify much of what you're doing.

https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism
https://github.com/andyw8/capybara-page-object